# Angular 5 --aot Vs Angular 5 --aot=false

Tags: javascript, angular

I use Angular 5.0.0 + rxjs ^5.5.2

When I use this command: `ng serve --aot=false`, my application is OK but when I use this command: `ng serve --aot` I have this error:

```
core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

I do not have any other messge. I can not copy/paste a part of my code because, 
I do not know where this comes from.

If you have any question, I am happy you answer them.

**EDIT 1:**

full stack:

```
webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1546 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at createDirectiveInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12211)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13645)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14077)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13986)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13673)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14077)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13986)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13673)
    at createRootView (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13535)
    at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14936)
    at createDirectiveInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12211)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13645)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14077)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13986)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13673)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14077)
    at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13986)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13673)
    at createRootView (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13535)
    at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14936)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:783)
    at resolvePromise (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:754)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:831)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4816)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1364)
defaultErrorLogger @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1546
```

**EDIT 2:**

`ng lint` command result:

```
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/app-config.ts[8, 7]: comment must start with a space
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/app-config.ts[10, 20]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, remove type annota
tion
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/app-config.ts[11, 19]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, remove type annota
tion
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/app-config.ts[16, 20]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, remove type annota
tion
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/app-config.ts[34, 9]: misplaced 'else'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/app-routing.module.ts[28, 1]: Exceeds maximum line length of 140
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/components/badge/badge.component.ts[3, 12]: The selector of the component "BadgeComponent" shou
ld have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/components/legend/legend.component.ts[4, 13]: The selector of the component "LegendComponent" s
hould have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/components/logo/logo.component.ts[9, 30]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal,
 remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/components/logo/logo.component.ts[3, 12]: The selector of the component "LogoComponent" should
have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/directives/track_scroll/track_scroll.directive.ts[12, 40]: == should be ===
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/directives/track_scroll/track_scroll.directive.ts[4, 24]: The selector of the directive "TrackS
crollDirective" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-08)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/home.component.ts[54, 13]: while statements must be braced
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/home.component.ts[23, 25]: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean literal, remove type
annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/home.component.ts[39, 36]: Type number trivially inferred from a number literal, remove type an
notation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/home.component.ts[40, 36]: Type number trivially inferred from a number literal, remove type an
notation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/home.component.ts[41, 22]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, remove type an
notation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/404/page-not-found.component.ts[5, 12]: The selector of the component "PageNotFoundCompon
ent" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[17, 14]: Type number trivially inferred from a number li
teral, remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[18, 17]: Type number trivially inferred from a number li
teral, remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[19, 22]: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean
literal, remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[20, 15]: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean
literal, remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[50, 17]: misplaced 'else'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[25, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const
' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[42, 17]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const
' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/customers/customers.component.ts[6, 12]: The selector of the component "CustomersComponen
t" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts[4, 12]: The selector of the component "DashboardComponen
t" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/employees/employees.component.ts[20, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' in
stead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/employees/employees.component.ts[34, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' in
stead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/employees/employees.component.ts[20, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const
' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/employees/employees.component.ts[34, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const
' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/employees/employees.component.ts[7, 15]: The selector of the component "EmployeesComponen
t" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts[13, 12]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, r
emove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts[39, 21]: expected a 'break' before 'case'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts[41, 21]: expected a 'break' before 'case'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts[43, 21]: expected a 'break' before 'default'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/login/login.component.ts[6, 15]: The selector of the component "LoginComponent" should ha
ve prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/logout/logout.component.ts[5, 15]: The selector of the component "LogoutComponent" should
 have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_details/order_details.component.ts[17, 26]: Type boolean trivially inferred from a
boolean literal, remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_details/order_details.component.ts[106, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or '
const' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_details/order_details.component.ts[106, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; u
se 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_details/order_details.component.ts[8, 12]: The selector of the component "OrderDeta
ilsComponent" should have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_stats/order_stats.component.ts[29, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const
' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_stats/order_stats.component.ts[34, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const
' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_stats/order_stats.component.ts[29, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'c
onst' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_stats/order_stats.component.ts[34, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'c
onst' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_stats/order_stats.component.ts[16, 23]: expected nospace before colon in property-d
eclaration
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/order_stats/order_stats.component.ts[9, 12]: The selector of the component "OrderStatsCom
ponent" should be named kebab-case and include dash (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-02)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[19, 15]: Type boolean trivially inferred from a boolean litera
l, remove type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[23, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[40, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[23, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' inst
ead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[40, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' inst
ead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[41, 13]: Identifier 'legendColors' is never reassigned; use 'c
onst' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/orders/orders.component.ts[8, 12]: The selector of the component "OrdersComponent" should
 have prefix "app" (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-02-07)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[9, 1]: space indentation expected
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[10, 1]: space indentation expected
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[22, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'c
onst' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[27, 9]: Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'c
onst' instead
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[22, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; us
e 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[27, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; us
e 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[9, 12]: The selector of the component "ProductSt
atsComponent" should be named kebab-case and include dash (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-02)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/pages/product_stats/product_stats.component.ts[21, 5]: Implement lifecycle hook interface OnIni
t for method ngOnInit in class ProductStatsComponent (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-09-01)
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[27, 13]: Identifier 'headers' is never reassigned; use 'con
st' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[28, 13]: Identifier 'token' is never reassigned; use 'const
' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[54, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[55, 13]: Identifier 'requestOptions' is never reassigned; u
se 'const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[67, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[68, 13]: Identifier 'requestOptions' is never reassigned; u
se 'const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[80, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[81, 13]: Identifier 'requestOptions' is never reassigned; u
se 'const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[93, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/api-request.service.ts[94, 13]: Identifier 'requestOptions' is never reassigned; u
se 'const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[37, 1]: Exceeds maximum line length of 140
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[28, 25]: Identifier 'newRow' is never reassigned; use 'const'
instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[27, 21]: Identifier 'items' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[34, 21]: Identifier 'returnObj' is never reassigned; use 'cons
t' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[18, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' inst
ead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[19, 13]: Identifier 'params' is never reassigned; use 'const'
instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/customer.service.ts[23, 13]: Identifier 'customerListSubject' is never reassigned;
 use 'const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/employee.service.ts[3, 53]: This import is blacklisted, import a submodule instead

ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/employee.service.ts[17, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' inst
ead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/employee.service.ts[18, 13]: Identifier 'params' is never reassigned; use 'const'
instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/login.service.ts[19, 24]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, re
move type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/login.service.ts[57, 17]: misplaced 'else'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/login.service.ts[29, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead
 of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/login.service.ts[31, 13]: Identifier 'bodyData' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/login.service.ts[35, 13]: Identifier 'loginDataSubject' is never reassigned; use '
const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[63, 1]: Exceeds maximum line length of 140
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[30, 25]: Identifier 'newRow' is never reassigned; use 'const' ins
tead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[29, 21]: Identifier 'returnObj' is never reassigned; use 'const'
instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[22, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead
 of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[23, 13]: Identifier 'params' is never reassigned; use 'const' ins
tead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[26, 13]: Identifier 'orderListSubject' is never reassigned; use '
const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[56, 25]: Identifier 'newRow' is never reassigned; use 'const' ins
tead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[55, 21]: Identifier 'returnObj' is never reassigned; use 'const'
instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[47, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead
 of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[48, 13]: Identifier 'params' is never reassigned; use 'const' ins
tead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/order.service.ts[52, 13]: Identifier 'orderDetailSubject' is never reassigned; use
 'const' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/product.service.ts[17, 11]: comment must start with a space
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/product.service.ts[27, 25]: Identifier 'newRow' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/product.service.ts[26, 21]: Identifier 'returnObj' is never reassigned; use 'const
' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/product.service.ts[18, 13]: Identifier 'me' is never reassigned; use 'const' inste
ad of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/product.service.ts[19, 13]: Identifier 'params' is never reassigned; use 'const' i
nstead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/api/product.service.ts[23, 13]: Identifier 'productList' is never reassigned; use 'con
st' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/auth_guard.service.ts[16, 13]: Identifier 'url' is never reassigned; use 'const' inste
ad of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[20, 27]: Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, re
move type annotation
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[47, 9]: misplaced 'catch'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[43, 13]: misplaced 'else'
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[40, 21]: Identifier 'userObj' is never reassigned; use 'const' in
stead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[38, 17]: Identifier 'userInfoString' is never reassigned; use 'co
nst' instead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[58, 13]: Identifier 'userObj' is never reassigned; use 'const' in
stead of 'let'.
ERROR: C:/workspace/POC/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT-SGR/webui/src/app/services/user-info.service.ts[66, 13]: Identifier 'userObj' is never reassigned; use 'const' in
stead of 'let'.
```

Comment: Are you using `TSLint`? It could help you with certain "dumb" errors you might have in your code.

Comment: I use tslint 5.7.0, how to dumb?

Comment: There is *a lot* of stuff you have to be very careful about to allow you to do AoT template compilation; you often can't just enable it and hope it will work. See https://objectpartners.com/2017/04/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-with-angular/ for starter.

Comment: If you can't explain the problem further, please, provide a way to replicate it then, e.g. a repo.

Comment: @sgrillon what **IDE** are you using. Most IDEs enable you to "turn on" lints. TSLint is the best lint _(and it's configured and provided by default)_ for typescript/angular projects. Once you successfully initiate it you should see a lot of **errors** in your code.

Comment: I use VSCode + ESLint plugin

Comment: @estus, My repository is here: https://github.com/sgrillon14/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT

Comment: if you want reproduce the problem: login with demo/demo + click on Products menu

Comment: I use `npm install eslint` but I do not have more message

Comment: Ok I've just cloned your project and your angular code has an **insane amount of TSLint errors**. Check on google how to activate tslint on VisualStudioCode and patch all of those errors. Do not use `eslint` it will not help much you in typescript files. The tslint.json inside of your webui folder is the config file for **TSLint** already configured by the angular team.

Comment: I run `ng lint`, I edit my post with the result

Comment: I would turn off `prefer-const`  and change `typedef` in `tslint.json` to get rid of irrelevant errors

Comment: I've quickly checked code base and found no glaring problems that would explain the error. Were there no TS errors on compilation? For example, I see `.flatMap(route => route.data)` but no `flatMap` operator was imported. This looks like a problem, but it won't cause the error you're having. As it was said, consider enabling TSLint, it could solve some problems for you. Otherwise you have to debug all places where you have `.subscribe()`, before and after the method.

Comment: There were no TS errors when compiling. I `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';` when I use `flatMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some people down voted while there was a real bug in the ngx-datatable library:

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1114
 and https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1104

Problem present in version 11.0.3 and solve in version 11.0.4

upgrade your pakage.json =>

"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.0.4",